# writing nodejs applications in kotlin with intellij idea ce

Tags: node.js, gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin, kotlin-js

I am trying to develop a Nodejs application using Kotlin 1.3.11 using the IntelliJ IDEA CE development environment. Unfortunately I haven't made any progress towards a running application. To ensure everything is setup correctly I want to print out a simple "hello world".

I searched for articles or tutorials about the topic but I didn't find much about bringing those three together (Kotlin, IntelliJ, Nodejs). The most specific ones which I found are: 
[a medium post](https://medium.com/@Miqubel/your-first-node-js-app-with-kotlin-30e07baa0bf7) and [another post](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin-javascript).

As far as I (believe to) know, there are three major steps:

- calling initializing the node app via npm and using npm to install the node dependencies like kotlin and expressjs
- creating a build.gradle to define other dependencies and tasks
- creating an IntelliJ IDEA project

I tried to perform the steps in different orders but I never came to a running application. Also I searched in IntelliJ's documentation but the Nodejs integration isn't a feature of the free community edition. There isn't a description how to make Kotlin and Nodejs work together too.

Has anyone here successfully tried to do that (or failed and knows why it is not going to work)? Do I have to use another IDE or to write my own build tools/toolchain?

Sincerely J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done this in IDEA CE, but theoretically, this should work.

Prerequisites: You have node installed, you can execute gradle tasks

This is a Minimum Configuration, There is a comprehensive one. Add a comment if intrested for that

**Step 1:**
Create a new Kotlin/JS project (with gradle) and make sure that your gradle build file looks like this

```
group 'node-example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.11'
    repositories {
      mavenCentral()
    }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
  }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin2js'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-js:$kotlin_version"
}

compileKotlin2Js.kotlinOptions {
  moduleKind = "commonjs"
  outputFile = "node/index.js"
}

task npmInit(type: Exec) {
  commandLine "npm", "init", "-y"
}

task npmInstall(type: Exec) {
  commandLine "npm", "install", "kotlin", "express", "--save"
}

task npmRun(type: Exec) {
  commandLine "node", "node/index.js"
}

npmRun.dependsOn(build)
```

**Step 2:**
 After syncing your `build.gradle` in step 1 run the gradle tasks `npmInit` and `npmInstall`

```
./gradlew :npmInit
./graldew :npmInstall
```

**Step 3:**
Create your kotlin file (`index.kt`/`main.kt`/`whatever.kt`) in `src/main/kotlin` and test the code below

```
external fun require(module:String):dynamic

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello JavaScript!")

    val express = require("express")
    val app = express()

    app.get("/", { req, res ->
        res.type("text/plain")
        res.send("Kotlin/JS is kool")
    })

    app.listen(3000, {
        println("Listening on port 3000")
    })
}
```

**Step 4:** **RT***F***A - Run The App**
Run the gradle task npmRun

```
./gradlew :npmRun
```

Hope that helps

Note:
1. This template was pulled from the medium post you asked above and modified a little
2. Remember to run your gradle tasks using `sudo` (if you are using linux)

Comment: thanks for your reply. your post was helpful but I couldn't make it work in IDEA.

Comment: Can you send your `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: Alternatively, you could clone https://github.com/miquelbeltran/kotlin-node.js and follow the instructions in the read me.**

I managed to get the Medium post to work by replacing `gradle build` with the following (since the post was published in 2017(!) and requires a much older version of Gradle):

Comment out the entire contents of `build.gradle` like so:

```
/*group 'node-example'
...
compileKotlin2Js.kotlinOptions {
  moduleKind = "commonjs"
  outputFile = "node/index.js"
}*/
```

Run this command in the command prompt: (3.4.1 was the latest version of Gradle just before the Medium post was published.)

```
gradle wrapper --gradle-version=3.4.1
```

Uncomment out `build.gradle`:

```
group 'node-example'
...
compileKotlin2Js.kotlinOptions {
  moduleKind = "commonjs"
  outputFile = "node/index.js"
}
```

Run this command in place of `gradle build`:

```
gradlew build
```

And finally run this command as in the post: (As of writing this answer on StackOverflow, Node.js does not be downgraded and the current LTS version 10.16.0 works perfectly.)

```
node node/index.js
```